# Get All the contents between two tags by excluding few tags in it

Tags: javascript, xml, regex

I want to retrieve everything between two tags of an xml by excluding few tags within that content. What is the regular epxpression for this? For example,in the below xml I want to extract everything between `<ASObject mappedClass="com.taliantsoftware.claims.indemnity.PayeeAllocationDTO" encoding="0">` and `</ASObject>` by excluding `<updated tagClass="boolean">false</updated> and    <voided tagClass="boolean">false</voided>` tags.

```
<ASObject mappedClass="com.taliantsoftware.claims.indemnity.PayeeAllocationDTO" encoding="0">
    <payeecustomerid tagClass="double">2004570.0</payeecustomerid>
    <amount tagClass="double">2131.2</amount>
    <new tagClass="boolean">true</new>
    <percent tagClass="double">100.0</percent>
    <updated tagClass="boolean">false</updated>
    <voided tagClass="boolean">false</voided>
    <remainderindicator tagClass="boolean">true</remainderindicator>
    <detailamountstatustypecode tagClass="String">pnd</detailamountstatustypecode>
    <primary tagClass="boolean">true</primary>
    <mailtoindicator tagClass="boolean">true</mailtoindicator>
    <checkgroupnumber tagClass="double">1.0</checkgroupnumber>
    <detailamountstatustypename tagClass="String">Pending</detailamountstatustypename>
    </ASObject>
```

Comment: Strongly recommend **not** trying to use regular expressions to extract data from XML in a browser environment (assuming that's what you're using). You can readily get an XML DOM document object for the document and use that instead.

Comment: I am not using browser. I have a tool which gives me this kind of xmls as responses. I want to extract part of this xml and use it in the subsequent request. This is nothing to do with browser!!

Comment: Okay. If you tag a question `javascript` and it's not in a browser environment (you'll note I did flag that that was an assumption), you really should **say that** in the question, as the overwhelming majority of use of JavaScript is in the browser. What JavaScript environment are you using? NodeJS? Rhino? SilkJS? RingoJS? JScript?

Comment: @user1614862 Why do you have this tagged as "JavaScript" if you're not using the browser? Are you using NodeJS? Rhino? You should mention the environment in which you're using JS.

Comment: My tool supports javascript also. In the worst case scenario if it is not possible with regular expression then I would go for javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just remove updated and voided tags, this regex should work:

```
var clean_xml = xml.replace(/<(updated|voided).*</\1>/,'')
```

Notes:

- you can add other tags, but they can't be self-closing with this regex
- xml parsers are more reliable

**edit**

If you have to firstly capture the ASObject tag, the regex is not very pretty. Perhaps better with a recursive pattern.

```
/(<ASObject.*)<(updated|voided).*<\/\2>(.*)<(updated|voided).*<\/\4>(.*<\/ASObject>)/
```

And then concat the indexes 1,3,5 of the resulting array.

Comment: Actually my tool expects the regular expression and I use <ASObject mappedClass="com.taliantsoftware.claims.indemnity.PayeeAllocationDTO" encoding="0">([^^]*?)</ASObject> this expression to capture everything between those two tags with group expression $1 and wanted to filter out the mentioned tags from the captured content using regex only. If it is not possible with regex then only I will go for javascript.

Comment: Any solution with regular expression?